# drupal form with destination redirect

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-6, hook

I am trying what should be a simple line of code but isn't working. With the following code:

```
drupal_goto("user/register?destination=/node/1");
```

I am sending my visitors to a registration page which once completed and they hit the submit button, I then want them re-directed to node/1.

The problem is my is implemented in hook_init and my sites goes into an endless loop.

Can anyone suggest how I might get the code to execute once or a more suitable drupal hook to implement my code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? Do you redirect all users to the registration form from hook_init()? If all visitors are to either log in or register, why do you simply not just set "user/register" as the front page (via the administration pages)?

Comment: The big picture is my users are invited via email to join groups via a link in the email. The link brings them to my site where my code checks if their email address is registered. In case no, I redirect them to the registration page but once complete, I need them to be sent back to the original page where they can continue the group joining process

Comment: Ok, so show us the code that does the redirection, tell us where you placed it, and how the endless loop looks like (looping from where to where?).

Comment: Also, which version of Drupal do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the redirection to occur specifically when the user submits the registration form, then you're gonna want to alter the user_register form by implementing **hook_form_FORMID_alter** and adding the '#redirect' attribute, like:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORMID_alter().
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 * @return void
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#redirect'][] = 'node/1';
}
```

That way, Drupal will register the user and then send him/her to *node/1*.

Now, if you want this to happen after the user **logs in** (whether or not it is a "post-registration" login or a normal login), then you're probably gonna want to use drupal_goto() in an implementation of [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) in the 'login' operation (that is, when `$op == 'login'`)

Answer (score 1):

I think adding this to your template.php will do it:

```
    function phptemplate_menu_item_link($link) {
      if ($link['tab_root'] == 'user' && !empty($_GET['destination'])) {
        $link['localized_options']['query'] = drupal_get_destination();
      }
      return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
    }
```

I wrote a blog post about why I wanted to do this here: http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2013/04/11/maintain-destination-drupal-user-account-menu#.UWbt8hcmdIE and there's a couple of other user tips in that too which might help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to make sure that you are not already logged in, on node/1, user/register, or another inappropriate path before you do the redirect, otherwise you are just blindly redirecting and that results in the loop, right? Plus you also need to allow users to login, right?

So you can start by first making sure the user is not logged in and they aren't already on a user path to send anonymous users to the 'user' page (or user/register):

```
  if(($user->uid == 0) && (arg(0) != 'user')){
    drupal_goto('user');
  }
```

Then perform your `node/1` redirect using `hook_user_login()` rather than `hook_init()`.

At least that's what makes sense to me, based on my understanding of your use case.

You might also want to consider using the [Login destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module, which has both stable D6 and D7 releases.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. hook_user_login sounds like the answer I was looking for. However, I am using Drupal 6 and there does not seem to be an equivalent.